# Run JavaScript again after div content change

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i append a javascript script to a div at the first time it work and populate my div with external data and layout. But when i do it again at the same instance with the same javascript... noting happens

```
$('#JsModelSubmit').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.poptin-popup .js-container').empty(); 
    $('#os-widget-jssdk').remove(); // Delete the script from the DOM
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.poptin-popup .js-container').append($('#AddJsInput').val());
    },300)

    $('.poptin-popup .js-container').attr('data-script',$('#AddJsInput').val());
    $(".poptin-popup .thumbnail-js").attr('src','').fadeOut();
    $("#addJsModel").fadeOut();
});
```

And example script that i append is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, s, id){
var js,
fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
r = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000000);
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.async=1;
js.src = "https://www.opinionstage.com/assets/loader.js?" + r;
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'os-widget-jssdk'));
</script><div class="os_widget" data-comments="false" data-of="outbraininteractive" data-path="/outbraininteractive/quiz-novice-or-wiz-test-your-digital-marketing-skills" id="os-widget-39833"></div>
```

First time

[image]

This is the result that i'm getting:

[image]

Second time and so on this is the result that i'm getting:

[image]

Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/86c9vkog/3/

Please help! Thank!

Comment: try $(document).on('click','.JsModelSubmit',function(e){}); use class instead of id for button

Comment: Not working! Thank!

Comment: Maybe `.load()` may help. `$('.poptin-popup .js-container').append($('#AddJsInput').val()).load()`

Comment: Can you also share related markup?

Comment: create a jsfiddle with markup

Comment: james -> not working!

Comment: create a jsfiddle with markup -> it's complicate

Comment: Make it simple ... [mcve].

Comment: Note deleting the script element does not remove the actual code from memory. Meaning any code it has setup is still possibly running, so when you try to readd the script again it probably detects it was already loaded and stops. Read the documentation for whatever api you are using to see how to generate a new item

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or [plnkr](https://plnkr.co)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/86c9vkog/3/ -> jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the JavaScript is loaded and executed, there is no link between it and the script element that loaded it at all. So, we cannot remove it.

But, by using `iFrame` we can bypass this behavior.

See the [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/86c9vkog/4/).

Why `iFrame` works?

By definition, `iFrame` embeds a new document `context`. So, the original page `context` and the `iFrame` page context are different. Whatever attached to the `iFrame` belongs to its own context.

> The HTML  element represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page. In HTML 4.01, a document may contain a head and a body or a head and a frameset, but not both a body and a frameset. However, an  can be used within a normal document body. Each browsing context has its own session history and active document. The browsing context that contains the embedded content is called the parent browsing context. The top-level browsing context (which has no parent) is typically the browser window.

Learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

```js
$(document).on('click','#JsModelSubmit',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#js-container').empty();
  iframe($('#AddJsInput').val());
});
function iframe(script){
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute('id', 'iframeId');
  iframe.setAttribute('src', 'about:blank');
  var adContainer = document.getElementById('js-container');
  adContainer.appendChild(iframe);
  var doc = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;
  if (doc.document){
    doc = doc.document
  }

  doc.open();
  doc.write(script);
  doc.close();
}
```

```css
#js-container{
  background:red;
  width:960px;
  heigth: 750px;
}
iframe{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="js-container">asdasdasd</div>
<textarea id="AddJsInput" rows="10" cols="1000"></textarea>
<button id="JsModelSubmit">Append</button>

<!-- Append this js code

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, s, id){
var js,
fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
r = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000000);
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.async=1;
js.src = "https://www.opinionstage.com/assets/loader.js?" + r;
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'os-widget-jssdk'));
</script><div class="os_widget" data-comments="false" data-of="outbraininteractive" data-path="/outbraininteractive/quiz-novice-or-wiz-test-your-digital-marketing-skills" id="os-widget-39833"></div>

-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is that when `loader.js` is loaded the first time it creates the `OpinionStage` object and when it's loaded the second time it doesn't do the initialization again because `OpinionStage` object already exists.

To make the snippet work you need to add `window.OpinionStage = null` before creating the script element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, s, id){
var js,
fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
r = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000000);
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
window.OpinionStage = null;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.async=1;
js.src = "https://www.opinionstage.com/assets/loader.js?" + r;
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'os-widget-jssdk'));
</script><div class="os_widget" data-comments="false" data-of="outbraininteractive" data-path="/outbraininteractive/quiz-novice-or-wiz-test-your-digital-marketing-skills" id="os-widget-39833"></div>
```

Comment: Ok!

But how i can do it Automatically? Let say that you can append any script that you want. How can i make sure that it will work with every script Automatically that my clients try to append?

Comment: It depends on the script. If the script does checks for existance of an object before initializing and doesn't load if it exists, you have to set that object to a falsy value if you want the script to load again.